# What is this vine with large heart-shaped leaves found in western New York state?

Tags: identification, vines

This vine grows in many locations in the [village of Newark, NY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newark,_New_York); oddly, I've never noticed it anywhere else (perhaps a specialty of a local nursery?)

It is a deciduous perennial with relatively-small white flowers.  The vines themselves do overwinter (in Zone 6A), so it spreads with an almost [kudzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kudzu)-like vigor.

[image: Porch overgrown by vine with large heart-shaped leaves]
[image: Mystery vine with large heart-shaped leaves]
[image: House overgrown by vine with large heart-shaped leaves]
[image: Column next to vine with large heart-shaped leaves]

Comment: I thought it might actually be Kudzu.

Comment: Can you get (well, I guess at this point in the year, find on your camera/computer) a closer-in picture to help with ID?

Comment: I've added another image (the closest one I could find) which might help a little -- I'll look for an actual close-up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Dutchman's Pipe, AKA Pipevine, or Aristolochia macrophylla.

See the picture at [this site](https://www.99roots.com/en/plants/dutchman-s-pipe-p32541).

I could be wrong, especially as I don't know that this comes with white flowers in any variety (I could be wrong), but it looks the same. It's vigorous and can handle that zone and colder (to hardiness zone 4).

Comment: It was a favourite plant for porches in the fifties.

Comment: If the plant produces flowers which are more yellow/greenish, yet pale or whitish looking, then it is Aristolochia macrophylla.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any pictures I took with flowers -- so I'm guessing my recollection of white flowers is wrong (it's been years!), since in every other way, the Dutchman's Pipe looks just like the mystery vine.  Thanks, folks!

Comment: It's the host plant for the Pipevine Swallowtail Butterfly! It has odd shaped yellowish flowers. The Pipevine caterpillars look creepy cool. Please don't use any pesticides around the vine-it will kill the butterfly caterpillars. The Pipevine butterfly lays red/orange eggs.